# Slick Slider Filter By Class

Tags: javascript, html, bulma

The correct text pops up on the slides, but when I press filter the entire carousel dissapears and no errors are in the console

```
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("red");

if (slides != null) {
  $(sliderClass).slick('slickUnfilter');
  $(sliderClass).slick('slickFilter', slides);
}
```

Carousel markup

```
<div class="carousel">      
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd recommend you edit your question and add  html  code instead of the html templating code you currently have so that people have an easier time helping you

Comment: If the code isn't working, why write it in a snippet?

Comment: I edited the question, do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is the answer

```
                $(sliderClass).slick('slickFilter', $('.red').parent().parent());
```